# Cytoscape js qtip on right click

Tags: qtip, qtip2, cytoscape.js

I am trying to show qtip on the right click event of the nodes.
I already did it on mouseover or click events and they worked. However I can not make it work on right click.

```
position: {
    my: 'top left',
    at: 'bottom right',
    adjust: { method: 'none' }
},
style: {
    classes: 'qtip-rounded'
},
show: {
    event: 'mouseover'
}
```

Any guesses?
I also checked this: http://qtip2.com/guides#events.rightclick
It did not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use DOM events like the qtip docs suggest, as graph elements are not HTMLElements.  You should use Cytoscape events.

`cxttap` : http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/user-input-device-events